# how to install Apache-1.3.41+ PHP-5.2.6 on windows xp

Tags: php, apache, api, windows-xp, yahoo

I want develop yahoo API( http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/sample/auctions/sample10.html ),so I need install Apache-1.3.41+ PHP-5.2.6 on my windows XP computer.
I know how to install PHP - 5.3 + Apache 2 ,but I find this is different from Apache-1.3.41+ PHP-5.2.6 installion.

Someone can provide toturials about install Apache-1.3.41+ PHP-5.2.6 on windows XP.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can`t you use WAMP or XAMP?

Comment: the version is too old, I cant find source,can you provide download link.

Comment: take a look at uniformserver.com (most stable and up to date platform)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you install a long-time distribution of Apache, MySQL, PHP, and Perl for Windows.

http://www.indigostar.com/indigoampp.php

I have used it for Apache development on Windows various times for over 10 years. Ignore the website note that says "initial release 2009." This software has a long history and has even been developed parallel to Windows XP, so it is definitely going to work for you.

It's really very good.